tabular vs tblr environment
I've recently looked into the tabularray package and the possibilities its tblr environment offers here and here, and I've been amazed by its versatility. Not only do the tables look better in terms of vertical spacing by default, but it also has a mandatory argument which can take keyvalues (\begin{tblr}{<keyvals>}), and that helps to clearly distinguish between the code related to modifying the contents of the table and the actual data included in the table. In addition, that also seems to make the customization potential of tables produced in tblr greater than tabular.
As such, it seems to me like the tblr environment is advantageous to the classic tabular environment in every regard, and that makes me wonder: Is there any instance where tabular is better? What are the pros and cons of each?
I wasn't able to find a thread comparing these 2 environments directly here so I thought we could start one now and benefit others with a deeper understanding of each!

The main disadvantage of tblr is speed. That's not so important if you compile on your own computer, but on services like overleaf, document only have a limited time before the compilation times out.

How much slower, and does the time increase linearly or exponentially as the table gets more complex. At what level of complexity do the speed differences become noticeable?

You can find some statistics from overleaf at https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/66393444#66393444

There are also some limitations for the content of cells: macros with optional arguments might require a bit of creativity. All-in-all I would use tabularray.

I use the Overleaf editor, and I think quite a lot of other people do so, too. Thus, I think it may be a good idea if you could make an answer to this question diving into the compilation speed issue including the picture in the link you referenced:)

I'll ask @yo' if he would like to post an answer

currently tabularray doesn't support PDF tagging.

I only use tabularray to answer questions which use it. tabular has the advantage of simplicity. tabularray has tens of pages of documentation. if I only need a simple table, I see no reason not to prefer the simpler solution.
