Vertical text alignment in table row with images and different text alignments
I am having trouble with vertical alignment of text in a table row.
My problem boils down to this:

I would like the rightmost cell's content to be vertically aligned at the bottom of its cell, while keeping the alignment of the first two cells as is.
How can I achieve that? This is my current source:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{| l | X | X |}
    \hline
    \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm,valign=t]{example-image}
     &
    This text should be aligned at the top of the cell.
    This text should be aligned at the top of the cell.
    This text should be aligned at the top of the cell.
    This text should be aligned at the top of the cell.
    This text should be aligned at the top of the cell.
     &
    This text should be aligned at the bottom of the cell.
    \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}

I feel this may be different from other info found in the questions linked in the comments because there are here more than two columns, we don't know which column will hold the highest cell, and the non-highest cells may need to have different vertical alignments from each other.

This question is similar to: Vertical alignment in tabular cells with variable height. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz OK, just added a paragraph on why I think it's different.

You could switch to the tabularray package:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{| l | X | X[valign=f] |}
    \hline
    \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm,valign=t]{example-image}
     &
    This text should be aligned at the top of the cell.
    This text should be aligned at the top of the cell.
    This text should be aligned at the top of the cell.
    This text should be aligned at the top of the cell.
    This text should be aligned at the top of the cell.
     &
    This text should be aligned at the bottom of the cell.
    \\
    \hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}



Aha, interesting! How would I move here the image to the bottom of the cell? l[valign=f] is not working as an alignment.

@Jean-PhilippePellet \begin{tblr}{| Q[valign=f] | X | X[valign=f] |}     \hline     \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm,valign=b]{example-image}

I'm now reading the docs for tabularray. It's a brilliant package. I don't see why we should use any other table-layout system, it seems to cover everything in more intuitive and powerful ways than what existed before.

@Jean-PhilippePellet I completely agree with your conclusion, but be aware that there are some downsites https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/730023/tabular-vs-tblr-environment

@samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz I see what you mean, now. My 160-page document with quite a few tables compiles about 2.5 times more slowly with tabularray and tblr environments instead of my old tabular and tabularx. Still totally worth it, IMO.
